Why does my Inno Setup script fail to detect 32-bit or 64-bit applications from the Uninstall registry hive?
I'm using Inno Setup to check if certain applications (starting with "XYZ") are installed on the system by searching the Uninstall registry keys. My script checks both 32-bit and 64-bit Uninstall hives, but it doesn't always find the applications, especially when searching for 32-bit applications on a 64-bit system or vice versa.
For example, the code does not seem to find Notepad++  at all according the LOG, this entry exists in my registry, but the log does not show it;
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++
function IsXYZInstalled: Boolean;
var
  KeyNames: array[0..3] of String;
  i, j: Integer;
  SubkeyNames: TArrayOfString;
  SubkeyNames2: TArrayOfString;
  DisplayName: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  


  // Initialize array of registry paths for the Uninstall keys
  KeyNames[0] := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall';
  KeyNames[1] := 'Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall';
 
  
  
  // Iterate through each registry path
  for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
  log('start HKEY_CURRENT_USER USER '+KeyNames[i]);
    // Get the list of subkeys (each representing an installed application)
    if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, KeyNames[i], SubkeyNames) then
    begin
      // Iterate through each subkey
      for j := 0 to GetArrayLength(SubkeyNames) - 1 do
      begin
        log (inttostr(j)+ ' ' +KeyNames[i] + '\' + SubkeyNames[j]);
          log(DisplayName);
          
        // Try to read the DisplayName value for each subkey
        if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, KeyNames[i] + '\' + SubkeyNames[j], 'DisplayName', DisplayName) then
        begin
          // Check if the DisplayName starts with "XYZ"
          if Pos('XYZ', DisplayName) = 1 then
          begin
            Result := True;
            Exit;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
            
  // Iterate through each registry path
  for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
  log('START HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\'+KeyNames[i]);
    // Get the list of subkeys (each representing an installed application)
    if RegGetSubkeyNames(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KeyNames[i], SubkeyNames2) then
    begin
      // Iterate through each subkey
      for j := 0 to GetArrayLength(SubkeyNames2) - 1 do
      begin
        log (inttostr(j)+ ' HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ' +KeyNames[i] + '\' + SubkeyNames2[j]);
        // Try to read the DisplayName value for each subkey
        if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KeyNames[i] + '\' + SubkeyNames2[j], 'DisplayName', DisplayName)            then
        begin
        log (inttostr(j)+ ' !HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ' +KeyNames[i] + '\' + SubkeyNames2[j]+'\'+DisplayName);
          // Check if the DisplayName starts with "XYZ"
          if Pos('XYZ', DisplayName) = 1 then
          begin
            Result := True;
            Exit;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  
end;


Thanks a lot! it seem to work, so I am closing this one now
